# How to run async function forever (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

How do I use asyncio and run the function forever. I know that there's `run_until_complete(function_name)` but how do I use `run_forever` how do I call the async function?

```
async def someFunction():
    async with something as some_variable:
        # do something
```

I'm not sure how to start the function.

Comment: You know there's `run_until_complete(function_name)`, could you provide the documentation to it ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, an example can be found here in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-future-with-run-until-complete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`run_forever` doesn't mean that an async function will magically run forever, it means that the *loop* will run forever, or at least until someone calls `loop.stop()`. To literally run an async function forever, you need to create an async function that does that. For example:

```
async def some_function():
    async with something as some_variable:
        # do something

async def forever():
    while True:
        await some_function()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(forever())
```

This is why `run_forever()` doesn't accept an argument, it doesn't care about any particular coroutine. The typical pattern is to add some coroutines using [`loop.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task) or equivalent before invoking `run_forever()`. But even an event loop that runs no tasks whatsoever and sits idly can be useful since another thread can call [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) and give it work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to exactly what you mean when you say *I'm not sure how to start the function*. If you're asking the question in the literal sense:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

If you wish to add a function to the loop before initialising the loop then the following line prior to `loop.run_forever()` will suffice:

```
asyncio.async(function())
```

To add a function to a loop that is already running you'll need `ensure_future`:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(function(), loop=loop)
```

In both cases the function you intend to call must be designated in some way as asynchronous, i.e. using the `async` function prefix or the `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator.

Comment: But this doesn't start the function, it never calls the function.

Comment: You need to add the task containing the function to the loop.

Comment: I don't understand. How do I call the function "async def someFunction()" and make it loop forever?

Comment: I've added extra detail to my answer

Comment: I literally still don't understand. If I use `asyncio.async(function())` at the end of my script the script just ends, as if it's not looping. If I add `loop.run_forever()` after it still doesn't work. I really don't understand, how do I start a function that runs forever...

Comment: Note that `asyncio.async` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) and is an alias for `asyncio.ensure_future`. Also, when the argument is a coroutine, `loop.create_task()` is [preferred](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555).